# PDO multiple inner joins appear to be looping

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using `INNER JOIN` for the first time and I'm a little confused.

I have 3 tables:

```
dog
client
dogclient
```

I'm trying to get information from both the `client` and `dog` tables for every record in the `dogclient` table. when i do, the result is this:

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"Sparky","Forename":"Jamie","Surname":"McAllister"},
{"ID":"1","Name":"Sparky","Forename":"Jamie","Surname":"McAllister"},
{"ID":"2","Name":"Scruff","Forename":"Jamie","Surname":"McAllister"},
{"ID":"2","Name":"Scruff","Forename":"Jamie","Surname":"McAllister"}]
```

The function i'm using to make this query is:

```
function getAll(){

    $conn = self::connect();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT dog.ID, dog.Name, client.Forename, client.Surname FROM dogclient INNER JOIN client ON dogClient.ClientID INNER JOIN dog ON dogclient.DogID"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $response = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $response;
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

or, does anyone know a better way to do this?

if it helps, there are only 2 dogs in the `dog` table, one client in the `client` table, and 2 records in the `dogclient` table, so i was expecting 2 results

Comment: This is a pure MySQL related question, I suggest removing the PHP tag and code. Just state how your table(s) are structured and a nicely formatted SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INNER JOIN client ON dogClient.ClientID = client.ClientID INNER JOIN dog ON dogclient.DogID = dog.DogID
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to this answer, The answer is correct other than the field names being wrong :) thanks